# Sync encrypted drives

Tags: backup, file-synchronization, encryption, synchronization

I'm looking for a solution that can encrypt AND sync targeted drives/folders in one go.  What I am trying to accomplish is that I have an encrypted partition (currently using Truecrypt, but any other solution will do) which I store my private files.  I also have another computer at a remote site with a copy of this encrypted drive which I need to keep in sync with very few efforts.

Cloud storage is not an option in my country where the internet is extremely slow and expensive. So I have to use external HDDs to directly copy the files.

Backup software with encryption is also not an option because two persons could potentially work on both computers simultaneously and then the file changes needs to be synced.

All sync apps that I have tried exposes my private files on the external HDD with no encryption.

I could install Truecrypt on the external HDD too, but to open each Truecrypt volume (re-entering the password), sync files, remember to close the correct Truecrypt volumes are a very cumbersome task.

Are there any tools out there that would make the task of synchronizing the two computer's files using external HDD's easy and safe?

Comment: Take a look at SyncBackPro and SyncBackSE at http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/compare.html  They both might work for your needs.  Note that their freeware offering, SyncBackFree, does not include encryption, so it will not work for your needs.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Using TrueCrypt with SyncBackPro is another option. SBP can detect when a specific physical drive is mounted and automatically mount via TC and then sync. On Windows if you are using a Pro or Enterprise version, Bitlocker would also work.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install Bitlocker on the external HDD. SBP is almost what I am looking for, except that it reveals the files on the external HDD as encrypted zip files.  I was hoping for something a bit more private.